# Inserting data on PostGRES using Java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

How should I insert data on postgers database using java? Here is the code I'm executing, which throws me an error:

```
public static Result add() {
    response().setContentType("application/json");
    JsonNode val = request().body().asJson();
    System.out.println(val);
    ObjectNode result= new ObjectNode(val);
    String firstname=val.findPath("firstname").textValue();
    System.out.println(firstname);
    String lastname=val.findPath("lastname").textValue();
    System.out.println(lastname);
    result.put(firstname, 1);
    result.put(lastname, 2);
    System.out.println(result);
    Ebean.save(result);
    return ok(index.render("Record has been inserted"+user));
}
```

Comment: You could use plain [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) for persistence of data. JPA and Spring JPA are other options.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Result add() throws Exception {
    Myapps user = new Myapps();
    try {
        JsonNode requestBody = request().body().asJson();
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

                     ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerForUpdating(user);

                     user = reader.readValue(requestBody);
        user.save();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ok(Json.toJson("inserted value is" + user));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play uses [Ebean](http://www.avaje.org/) (by default) as the persistence framework which uses JPA for mapping entities. See the [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaEbean) for more.
Therefore you can only persist JPA annotated entities. You are trying to persist a Jackson ObjectNode object which is obviously not a JPA annotated entity.

Assuming what you are trying to persist is a Person, your code would change to the following:

app/models/Person.java

```
package models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen", sequenceName = "person_id_seq")
    public Long id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

}
```

In your controller class:

```
public static Result add() {
    JsonNode val = request().body().asJson();
    System.out.println(val);

    String firstname=val.findPath("firstname").textValue();
    System.out.println(firstname);
    String lastname=val.findPath("lastname").textValue();
    System.out.println(lastname);

    Person person = new Person();
    person.firstName = firstname;
    person.lastName = lastname;
    person.save();

    return ok(index.render("Record has been inserted"+person));
}
```

**NOTE** You will have to configure your jdbc driver for Postgres as well. [See here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsJDBC).

This code will persist your "person" record into a table called 'Person'.

Comment: i tried this,each time i compile the record will inserted in db,incase i refresh the page and insert means it throw error

Comment: @user3759092 Have a look at this answer and adjust the annotation on Person.id as indicated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13107516/2408961