# How to use auto-generated @Id in PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-batch

I'm using a `PreparedStatement` for batch inserting values into a `postgres` database, as follows:

```
JdbcBatchItemWriter<FieldSet> w = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
w.setDataSource(ds);
w.setSql("INSERT INTO my_table(firstname,lastname) VALUES(?,?)");
w.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new ItemPreparedStatementSetter() {
    //pseudocode
    ps.setString(1, "test");
    ps.setString(2, "testname");
});
```

Problem: my entity class also has an auto generated `@Id`, which is not set here.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String firstname, lastname;
}
```

As a result, this causes the following error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: NULL-value in column ?id? violates Not-Null-Constraint.

Of course, as I didn't set the `id`. But how can I let it be auto generated?

Comment: does your table reflect the postgres standard for auto generated? see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13107516/62201 if not, why not? and how do you want the id to be generated?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with a JPA entity, you can't use `JdbcBatchItemWriter`, who is not aware of JPA annotations, but [`JpaItemWriter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.html) instead.

A sample configuration would be:

```xml
<bean id="jpaItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

where `entityManagerFactory` is your entity manager factory bean. Then you can use this `ItemWriter` directly or inject it as a delegate in another `ItemWriter`.

If you want to do batching with JPA, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10584179/1743880).

Comment: I cannot use `JpaItemWriter` as I have to insert a few million rows into the database, and `JpaItemWriter` is too slow for this opteration (about 4times slower than `JdbcBatchItemWriter`).

Comment: @membersound Then you should have stated it in the question instead of downvoting my answer because I proposed it (I'm not in your head). On another note, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10584717/1743880) for batching with JPA.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Anyways the question is "how to use an auto-generated in in PreparedStatement". I cannot switch to JPA batching as this is too slow!

Comment: @membersound And I answered, "you cannot do that, switch to `JpaItemWriter` instead". I don't think telling "you really can't do that, do this instead" is worth a downvote... If JPA batching is too slow for your requirements, you have to drop JPA and your entities and make your inserts by hand: set a sequence on the DB and select that to get your generated id.