# Postgres look for relation with wrong name

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

In Postgres I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE punching_history (
    id_punching serial NOT NULL,
    punching_date timestamp without time zone,
    -- other fields
    CONSTRAINT punching_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_punching)
);

CREATE TABLE punching()
INHERITS (punching_history);
```

and this sequence (auto generated by serial field of punching_history):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE punching_history_id_punching_seq
INCREMENT 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
START 1
CACHE 1;
```

The insert (persist) into punching table works, but sometimes, apparently without reason, it fails with this error:

```
"HTTP 500 Internal Server Error - could not extract ResultSet 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation 
<schema_name>.punching_id_punching_seq does not exist Position: 16"
```

In Hibernate primary key is mapped as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID_PUNCHING", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer idPunching;
```

Why does Postgres look for punching_id_punching_seq relation? It has always been punching_history_id_punching_seq.

Thanks

Comment: You may have to change the strategy of generated values to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` - have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107516) (but note [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200060) too).

Comment: Try to make `ID_PUNCHING` to low case `@Column(name = "id_punching", unique = true, nullable = false)`. I had same problem and this helped to me

Comment: @IgorCova Your solution seems a little strange, but I'll try it :D

Comment: It helped to you?

Comment: It's early to say, I have to try it for a sufficiently long period

Comment: @IgorCova The workaround did not work, the problem occurred again

Comment: You need to profile your program, identify issues. it's not normal behavior

Comment: The problem exists also after reboot of Postgres but disappears (temporarily) after reboot of application server (JBoss), then I believe the cause must be looked for in mapping between field class and table column

Comment: @collapsar Changing the strategy seems to work, although, as you can see in the other answer, the best strategy should be GenerationType.IDENTITY